# Oleview not available on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, viewer, adk

i want to get a COM viewer and i found oleview from Microsoft. So... this is verry nice that Microsoft delivers a COM Viewer by itself but i cant download it from the official Microsoft Website or from the ADK. I installed it, i reinstalled it, etc... but Oleview.exe is not on the ADK.

I found some posts that some people have oleview.exe installed and they are running but i dont want to install it from a third-party website.

Is Oleview still available on Windows 10 or is it just for other Versions of Windows?

BTW: I have Windows 10 Enterprise, Version: 1511 with the newest ADK which is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/tyranid/oleviewdotnet seems to work. There are 32 and 64 bit viewers in it.

Comment: Note that while OleViewDotNet is a very nice tool it is an alternative to Microsoft's oleview program, so this only indirectly answers the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/ole-com-object-viewer

> The OLE/COM Object Viewer, oleview.exe, is an application **supplied
> in the Windows SDK** that displays the COM objects installed on your
> computer...
>
> The OLE/COM Object Viewer app is found in the Windows SDK in \Program
> Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10[version][architecture]\oleview.exe.

The Windows SDK download presently is located at: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/

For example on my Win10 PC, it is located in:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\oleview.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no option to enable it back. I tried one other .EXE but it was just a virus(i tried it in a VM)

It seems that Oleview is no longer available and supported.

Comment: oleview.exe is part of the Windows Developers Kit. 32bit and 64bit versions are available and they do work on Windows 11.